# Async call in JavaScript Loop - Apache Cordova

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, android-contacts, visual-studio-cordova

I have an array of contacts being returned from my database which I need to check are on the device and then save/update the contact on the device. The problem is the `navigator.contacts.find(fields, findSuccess, findError, options);` call in cordova is asynchronous.

The issue Im having is that the for loop is going to its next iteration with new data **before** the `onSuccess` is being fired. This means it will try to save/update with the same data twice or no data at all.

```js
$scope.syncContacts = function () {

        var table = AzureService.getTable('contact');
        table.read().done(function (results) {
            console.log("Results: ", results);
            for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
                    //create a contact object to save or update
                    var emails = [];
                    var phoneNumbers = [];
                    var name = new ContactName();
                    var contactToUpdate = navigator.contacts.create();
                    contactToUpdate.note = results[i].id;
                    name.givenName = results[i].firstname;
                    name.familyName = results[i].lastname;
                    phoneNumbers[0] = new ContactField('mobile', results[i].mobilephone, true);
                    phoneNumbers[1] = new ContactField('home', results[i].homephone, false);
                    emails[0] = new ContactField('work', results[i].email, true);
                    contactToUpdate.name = name;
                    contactToUpdate.phoneNumbers = phoneNumbers;
                    contactToUpdate.emails = emails;

                    //Search for the contact on the device
                    var options = new ContactFindOptions();
                    options.filter = results[i].id;
                    options.multiple = false;
                    var fields = ["*"];
                    navigator.contacts.find(fields, foundSuccess, foundError, options);

                    function foundSuccess(contact) {
                        if (contact.length > 0) {
                           
                            contactToUpdate.id = contact[0].id;
                            contactToUpdate.rawId = contact[0].rawId;
                            contactToUpdate.phoneNumbers[0].id = contact[0].phoneNumbers[0].id;
                            contactToUpdate.phoneNumbers[1].id = contact[0].phoneNumbers[1].id;
                            contactToUpdate.emails[0].id = contact[0].emails[0].id;
                            console.log('about to save this', contactToUpdate);
                            contactToUpdate.save(upSuccess, upError);
                            function upSuccess() {
                                console.log('updated a contact!');
                            }
                            function upError(ContactError) {
                                console.log('error updating a contact!');
                            }
                        }
                        else {
                            //The contact does not exist on the device. Just save it.
                            console.log('non existent contact: ', contactToUpdate);
                            contactToUpdate.save(saveSuccess, SaveError);
                            function saveSuccess() {
                                console.log('saved a contact!');
                            }
                            function SaveError() {
                                console.log('error saving a contact!');
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    function foundError() {
                        alert('Contact search failed: Undeleted Contact Search');
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    };
```

My question is, how can I deal with this? My thought was to maybe use a forEach as whats being returned is an array.

Will this ensure that only the correct data is being used or do I need to take another approach altogether?

Comment: forEach will work for you

Comment: @JaromandaX I'll test this later this evening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing to a forEach loop solved this problem